# How to enable type checking for rules that require type checking on the command line?

Tags: tslint

Some rules require type checking. I don't understand from the documentation about  [type checking](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/type-checking/) what to do to run it on the command line.

If I run somethink like

```
tslint --project admin/tslint.json "project/**/*.ts{,x}"
```

I get the error message

```
Invalid source file: project/main.ts. Ensure that the 
files supplied to lint have a .ts, .tsx, .d.ts, .js or .jsx extension.
```

The documentation says

> When using the CLI, the `--project` flag will automatically create a
>   program from the specified `tsconfig.json` file and enable rules that
>   require the type checker.

But I don't see the program generated by `tslint` nor do I understand how to run it.

So, what are the steps to run `tslint` with type checking form the command line?

Answer (score 0):

- The `--project` argument needs the typescript compiler `tsc` configuration file (typically `tsconfig.json`).
- The `--config` argument gets the `tslint` configuration (typically `tslint.json`):

So, the full command line is:

```
tslint --config tslint.json --project tsconfig.json
```

You don't have to specify the files on the command line -- they are found in the `tsconfig.json` file...